# Map Type Error in OCaml

Tags: mapping, ocaml, abstract

I'm creating a mapping of words from a list, but I'm getting this return value and the error below. When I add things to it manually, I'm able to `Map.find` without any issue. Is there a good resource for type errors like this?

```
#   val word_mapping : int DictMap.t list =
      [<abstr>; <abstr>; <abstr>; <abstr>; <abstr>; <abstr>; <abstr>; <abstr>;
       <abstr>]
    # DictMap.find "There" word_mapping;;
    Error: This expression has type int DictMap.t list
           but an expression was expected of type
             'a DictMap.t = 'a Map.Make(String).t
```

Answer (score 1):

You should reveal your code if you want better answers.

The typing error message has already explained what is wrong: you are not creating ONE map of words to ints of type `int DictMap.t`, but a list of MAPS of words to ints of type `int DictMap.t list`.  I guess your code is like

```
List.map (fun (k,v) -> DictMap.add k v DictMap.empty) [("a",1); ("b",2); ... ]
```

or something equivalent.

What you have to do instead is to start from one empty `DictMap.t` and grow it using list folding, for example:

```
List.fold_left (fun dict (k,v) -> DictMap.add k v dict) DictMap.empty [("a",1); ("b",2); ... ]
```